# Why didn't $\Pr \left( A \rightarrow B \right)$ catch on?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, history, logic

Students are conditioned to thinking in terms of IF-THEN statements even before high school, and courses offered at the university level often lead to the formalization of [material implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional). Material implication is a function that two Boolean values and returns/outputs a single Boolean value. One can use 'True' and 'False', but here I will use '1' and '0' respectively. Material implication can be written as a [piecewise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise) function (especially since I am not aware of a nice way to format [truth tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) here).

$$p \rightarrow q \triangleq \begin{cases} 1 & p = 1 \land q = 1 \\ 0 & p = 1 \land q = 0 \\ 1 & p = 0 \land q = 1 \\ 1 & p = 0 \land q = 0 \end{cases}$$

An [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of $ A \subseteq \Omega$ is a map $\mathbb{I}_A: \Omega \mapsto \{ 0, 1 \}$, and can be written explicitly in a piecewise fashion.

$$\mathbb{I}_A(\omega) \triangleq \begin{cases} 1 & \omega \in A \\ 0 & \omega \not\in A \end{cases}$$

We will interpret $\Pr(A)$ to be $\int_{\Omega} \mathbb{I}_A(\omega)dP$, and $\Pr(A \rightarrow B)$ to be $\int_{\Omega} \mathbb{I}_A(\omega) \rightarrow \mathbb{I}_B(\omega) dP$. Seeing an implication operator in the integrand is a novelty, but this implication on indicators can be re-written in terms of a new indicator. Thus it is an expression compatible with our existing understanding.

$$\mathbb{I}_A(\omega) \rightarrow \mathbb{I}_B(\omega) = \mathbb{I}_{C}(\omega) \triangleq \begin{cases} 1 & \omega \in A \land \omega \in B \\ 0 & \omega \in A \land \omega \not\in B \\ 1 & \omega \not\in A \land \omega \in B \\ 1 & \omega \not\in A \land \omega \not\in B \end{cases}$$

$$\Pr(C) = \int_{\Omega} \mathbb{I}_C(\omega) dP$$

At some point students encounter the mathematical fact that $\Pr \left( A \rightarrow B \right) \neq \Pr \left( B | A \right)$. Some mathematicians were motivated to develop [conditional event algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_event_algebra) that attempt to define these as equal, and I've [asked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_event_algebra) for applications of such algebras in the past. The [Goodman–Nguyen–Van Fraasen algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodman%E2%80%93Nguyen%E2%80%93Van_Fraassen_algebra) is an example of a conditional event algebra.

But even **without** getting into conditional event algebras, $\Pr \left( A \rightarrow B \right)$ is a defined quantity in the standard [Kolmogorov treatment of probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms) that I have yet to see used. Why are we not using it?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "$\Pr(A\to B)$"?

Comment: Are you familiar with Judea Pearl and Pr(B|do(A)) ?

Comment: At first I interpreted the notation $X \rightarrow Y$ in the same straightforward way as @Henry, but now the more I think about it, the less sure I am. Here $A$ and $B$ seem to be events, and the question tells us that $A \rightarrow B \equiv \mathbb{I_{\omega \in A}} \rightarrow \mathbb{I_{\omega \in B}}$, so that we can think instead about indicator random variables... but this doesn't seem to help, because the meaning of $X \rightarrow Y$ is just as unclear whether $X$ and $Y$ are events (subsets of the sample space) or random variables (functions mapping from sample space to real line)

Comment: $A \rightarrow B$ is unclear to me if $A$ and $B$ are events/sets because I'm not sure what one set implying another set means. Probably the best candidate definition is that it means $A \subset B$... but this is not itself an event/set, it's just an expression that's either true or false, so I don't see how it has a probability. Likewise, $\mathbb{I_{\omega \in A}} \rightarrow \mathbb{I_{\omega \in B}}$ is unclear to me because I don't know what one r.v. implying another r.v. means. And for this one I'm not sure I even have a good candidate definition. So maybe you could clarify the latter?

Comment: Okay, it hurts my brain a little, but I guess I get it. And it ends up lining up with what I (and @Henry) originally thought. Essentially we count up how much of the joint probability is NOT in $A \cap B^c$. So I guess I echo @Henry's question about when or whether this shorthand notation would be useful.

Comment: Galen, by "implies" do you mean "causes"?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that $A$ and $B$ are events, this seems in effect to be saying $\Pr(A  \rightarrow B)$ would mean $\Pr(A^c \cup B)$,

which is equal to $\Pr(B\mid A)+\Pr(B^c\mid A) \Pr(A^c)$

and  greater than $\Pr(B\mid A)$ unless one of the terms is $0$.

But the question is whether this notation would be useful in any sense.

Comment: How would $Pr(A \rightarrow B)$ "mean" $Pr(A^c \cup B)$? Does "mean" mean $=$, i.e. $Pr(A \rightarrow B) = Pr(A^c \cup B)$? Why are you comparing $Pr(A \rightarrow B)$ to a conditional probability?

Comment: If you are trying to connect $A \rightarrow B$ to determinism, then the probability statement is not needed, i.e. you would say $A \rightarrow B := Pr(B|A) = 1 \text{ and } Pr(B|A^c) = 0$. In other words, it doesn't make sense to enclose $A \rightarrow B$ with a probability operator.

Comment: @AdamO to the arrow here isn't deterministic or causal, it's material implication. "A (materially) implies B" if and only if "(not A) or B", hence the union of A complement and B.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your notational definitions, your probability statement is equivalent to:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(A \rightarrow B)
\equiv \mathbb{P}(\bar{A} \cup B)
= 1- \mathbb{P}(A \cap \bar{B}),
\end{align}$$

which can already be framed perfectly adequately in terms of existing probability notation.

Answer (score 2):

"Why didn't Pr(A→B) catch on?" begs the question. Who ever asserted such notation was necessary or useful in the first place? The only thing that makes sense inside of a probability operator is an event. So if A and B are events, you can consider $Pr(A \cup B)$ or $P(B|A)$ or any type of set theoretic operation, and then you have Bayesian type operations as you mentioned which is just a measure theoretic result. However, $\rightarrow$ is no set theory operator. If $A \rightarrow B$ is an event, then you can WLOG call it $Z$ in some separate event in a separate event space $C$, where you can have events like 1. A causes B 2. Not A causes not B 3. A doesn't cause not B (etc, for 2^3 permutations).

But defining causation as an event is difficult to wrap one's mind around. Nonetheless, I've seen examples of this in clinical trials, where based on physician review, they can look at proportions of patients on drugs who have adverse outcomes, and whether those outcomes are (in a blinded fashion) determined to have been related to the drug or not. Typically this is based entirely on subjective review, and is most strongly argued by a lack of any other explanation, which does not suffice to prove causality.

EDIT: as a final comment, since the OP's edit about "material implication" significantly simplified the question: it is quite confusing to use overlapping notation from logic and statistics. For instance, we already use the $\bar{X}$ to represent the sample average, rather than the complement of event $X$. $\rightarrow$ is already convergence/limit operator. As others have pointed out, it's just one additional typeset to create the event of material implication as $A^C \cup B$.

Comment: @Galen I think a little study of causality would greatly nuance your question. As a purely logical construct, $A \rightarrow B$ has no relation to probability or inference, because we deal with determinism and inductive arguments rather than experimental observation and design.

Comment: @Galen Bayes is also important to invoke for two reasons. 1 and most obviously is that we develop the probability operator conditional, i.e. $P(A|B) = P(A \cap B)/P(B)$. More subtle and not in the scope of *my* answer is that Bayesian probability, as a sense of belief rather than frequency, allows us to consider as "events" things that aren't observable, like hypotheses, or probability models. So $P(A \rightarrow B)$ could be notation essentially for the belief that $A$ "implies" $B$.

Comment: @Galen lastly, I'm quite aware of begging the question fallacy, and that is exactly my problem with the "question" here, the assumed step that anyone ever proposed this notation at all. I think myself and others agree it's confusing, and without an example, a reference, or a definition to help, we're all struggling to understand exactly what it even is.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer's already in your question. It's fairly natural to use the notation of the sentential calculus within probability statements when what we'd be happy to take as the probability of the sentence's being true corresponds to what you get from totting up the probabilities for all the possible states of affairs for which the sentence is true. And so you sometimes see $\Pr(\lnot p)$, $\Pr(p \lor q)$, & the like, where $p$ & $q$ are sentences; more often $\Pr(\lnot A)$, $\Pr(A \lor B)$, & the like, where $A$ & $B$ are sets<sup>†</sup>. Material implication is exceptional, however: $\Pr(p \rightarrow q)$ ought to mean $\Pr(q|p)$, we feel—the probability of "if there are dark clouds now, then it will rain soon" depends only on how often it tends to rain soon given that there are dark clouds now—but that conditional probability isn't what we end up with by treating $\Pr(p \rightarrow q)$ in the same way as the others. If it hasn't caught on in standard Probability Theory, it's some combination of its being unintuitive as explained above, its already being "taken" by conditional events algebras, & lack of demand for an especially concise notation for what it represents in standard P.T.

---

† The latter usage is a generally harmless abuse of notation, but I wonder if it doesn't contribute to puzzlement about what $\Pr(A \rightarrow B)$ means.