# Probability of two equivalent statements

Tags: probability, logic

Let A and B be two statements such that A is satisfied if, and only if, B is satisfied. Can we then say Pr{A} = Pr{B}?

Comment: Use logic to answer it yourself are $B \to A$ and $B \land A$ the same statement? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra

Comment: @Tim: What do you mean exactly with "are → and ∧ the same statement"? If A and B are equivalent, evidently → is true. I don't understand what you mean, sorry

Comment: The Axiom of Specification of set theory asserts these two statements determine the same event.  Thus, you are asking whether the probability of an event equals itself.  Equivalently, you are asking whether the probability of an event depends on how it is specified.  I bet you can answer either one of these questions correctly!  @Tim Your translation of this question into propositional logic is erroneous.

Comment: @whuber, the first thing to say here is that A=B, the rest follows

Comment: Computing probabilities of events reminds me of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/536049/why-didnt-pr-left-a-rightarrow-b-right-catch-on

Comment: @Aksakal However, we cannot conclude that the *statements* A and B are equal.  It is only supposed they specify the same set.  For instance, let A be the assertion "x is a negative real number and x is the square of a real number" and let B be the assertion "x is a real zero of the exponential function."  Each can be shown to imply the other, despite such different formulations.

Comment: @whuber, agreed, they are mapped to the same set.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it in an intuitive way: if 2 situations only occur together; for example, if someone goes running exactly every Sunday, no matter the weather, ... , the person can say: A = 'I go running', B = 'It is Sunday'. The probability for A is now the same as B since going for a run implies it is Sunday and being Sunday implies going for a run.

So yes, if A <=> B, then P(A) = P(B).